# Check for a 'Connection timed out'

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.0, cakeemail

There's some trick i can do to *check* if the $cake_email->send() get Connection timed out ?For example: if I get a Connection Timed Out, i use a especific setFlash warning the user about the time out and redirect him to somewhere.

In my case, the email is something *optional*, if it sends: nice! If it don't: no problem, just need to let the user know this

Actualy I'm using **IF** to check if it get some error, but this didn't *catch* the time out error

```
$cake_email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
$cake_email->emailFormat('html');
$cake_email->to($dados['Requisitante']['email']);
$cake_email->template('atualizacaoRequisicao', 'default');
$cake_email->subject('ATUALIZAÇÃO DE REQUISICÃO');
$cake_email->viewVars(array('dados' => $dados));
if($cake_email->send()){
    $this->setFlash('A requisição foi salva e o email notificando a alteração foi enviado para '.$dados['Requisitante']['email'], 'flash_success');
} else {
    $this->setFlash('A requisição foi alterada, porém o email nao foi enviado', 'flash_info');
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a try catch block?

Comment: Yeah man! This gave me the result i want!

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

[STLMikey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290293/stlmikey)'s comment (try/catch) solved my problem! Much more simple than I expected

I'll just let my actual code here in case of helping someone else with the same problem.

```
try {
    if($cake_email->send()){
        $this->setFlash('A requisição foi salva e o email notificando a alteração foi enviado para '.$dados['Requisitante']['email'], 'flash_success');
    } else{
        $this->setFlash('A requisição foi alterada, porém o email nao foi enviado', 'flash_info');
    }
} catch(Exception $ex){
    $this->setFlash('A requisição foi alterada, porém o email não foi enviado ('.$ex->getMessage().')<br>Você pode atualizar a requisição novamente para tentar reenviar o email', 'flash_info');
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $dados['Requisicao']['id']));
}
```